# Docker on Windows10 home - inside docker container connect to the docker engine

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

When creating a Jenkins Docker container, it is very useful to able to connect to the Docker daemon. In that way, I can start docker commands inside the Jenkins container.

For example, after starting the Jenkins Docker container, I would like to 'docker exec -it container-id bash' and start 'docker ps'.

On Linux you can use bind-mounts on /var/run/docker.sock. On Windows this seems not possible. The solution is by using 'named pipes'. So, in my docker-compose.yml file I tried to create a named pipe.

```
version: '2'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins-docker
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_docker
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    networks:
      - jenkins
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine
      # - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      # - /path/to/postgresql/data:/var/run/postgresql/data
      # - etc.
```

Starting docker-compose with this file, I get the following error:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is
>   the docker daemon running?

How can I setup the docker-compose file so that I can use the docker.sock (or Docker) inside the started container?

On Linux you can use something like volumes: /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock. This does not work in a Windows environment. When you add this folder (/var) to Oracle VM Virtualbox, it won't get any IP forever. And on many posts

Comment: Windows10 not use mobylinux vm? You setup your own virtual machine as host in virtualbox?

Comment: It looks that installing an linux /ubuntu VM is the best solution. I will start experimenting with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try was to start a Docker environment using "Docker Quickstart terminal". This is a good solution when running Docker commands **within that environment**.

When installing a complete CI/CD Jenkins environment via Docker means that WITHIN the Jenkins Docker container you need to access the Docker daemon. After trying many solutions, reading many posts, this did not work. @Paul Rey, thank you very much for trying all kinds of routes.

A good solution is to get an Ubuntu Virtual Machine and install it via the Oracle VM Virtualbox. It is then **VERY IMPORTANT** to install Docker via [this official description](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

Before installing Docker, of course you need to install Curl, Git, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose the daemon on `tcp://localhost:2375` without TLS in the settings. This way you can configure Jenkins to use the Docker API instead of the socket. I encourage you to read [this article by Nick Janetakis about "Understanding how the Docker Daemon and the Docker CLI work together"](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/understanding-how-the-docker-daemon-and-docker-cli-work-together).

And then there are several Docker plugins for Jenkins that allows this connection:

[image]

Also, you can find additional information in the [Docker plugin documentation on wiki.jenkins.io](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin):

```
def dockerCloudParameters = [
  connectTimeout:   3,
  containerCapStr:  '4',
  credentialsId:    '',
  dockerHostname:   '',
  name:             'docker.local',
  readTimeout:      60,
  serverUrl:        'unix:///var/run/docker.sock', // <-- Replace here by the tcp address
  version:          ''
]
```

EDIT 1:

I don't know if it is useful, but the Docker Daemon on Windows is located to `C:\ProgramData\docker` according to the [Docker Daemon configuration doc](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#docker-daemon-directory).

EDIT 2:

You need to say explicitly the container to use the `host` network because you want to expose both Jenkins and Docker API.
Following [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/), you only have to add `--network=host` (or `network_mode: 'host'` in docker-compose) to your container/service. For further information, you can read [this article](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) to understand what is the purpose of this network mode.

Comment: I used the CloudBees docker plugin. When I use the tcp://localhost:2375, or tcp://127.0.1:2375 or tcp://192.168.99.100:2375 gives the same error that docker cli cannot connect to the docker daemon.

Comment: I think the problem is that the container doesn't know this IP. You must use the option `--network=host` when running the Jenkins container. I edit my answer to add this.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Alas, all kinds of options (also with the network=host) did not help. I think at last the best solution is to get an Ubuntu virtual machine and install docker in it. This is the advised solution. I up-voted +1 for you helping and pointing to solutions. When you use this solution, please give it as a solution so I can mark it as the best solution.

Comment: Indeed you can use a Linux distribution, I would suggest it too but I know that was not your directly your issue. And most of the time the solution can't be only "Change your OS" :)

Comment: as you can read in the solution, thank you very much for helping.